# Тире у Солженицына

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> И в одном зале ― в том самом, где стоял сегодня огромный телевизор, он с порога внезапно прозревшими глазами увидел на верху противоположной стены большие портреты Желябова и Перовской.

Зачем здесь тире? Я бы понял, если бы оно было парным: второе — на месте запятой после "телевизор".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*И в одном зале ― **в том самом, где стоял сегодня огромный телевизор**, ― он с порога внезапно прозревшими глазами увидел на верху противоположной стены большие портреты Желябова и Перовской.*

Вставная конструкция **всегда выделяется двумя тире**, а выбирается только количество запятых.

В данном предложении на месте вставки знаков не было, в этом случая ставятся **два тире.**

Но здесь еще дополнительно ставится **запятая**, которая  **закрывает придаточное предложение** в составе вставки.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Answer (score 2):

[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119)

> Слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения, выделяются
>   (или отделяются) знаками препинания (запятыми, тире, двоеточием).
>   Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова именно, а
>   именно, то есть (при отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть
>   вставлены).

*И в одном зале, **именно** в том самом, где стоял сегодня огромный телевизор...*

> **При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным
>   членом предложения часто ставится тире**:
>    *Иногда что-нибудь хочется
>   сделать — почитать (Г.);
>
>   Разговор шёл один — о погоде;
>
>   Было ещё одно препятствие на пути учёных — суеверие островитян;  Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель.*

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что тире там действительно пропало после "телевизора". Только оно должно быть не вместо запятой , а после неё. Если это вставная пояснительная конструкция, то она должна выделяться **с двух сторон**. Заяптая тире тут "поглощать" не может (хотя это и очень путанный раздел пунктцуации, но в целом запятая и тире сохраняются, если ставятся по *разным мотивам*).

ну а если считаь тире одинарным, то реально непонятно, что оно тут делает.

Вы знаете, я попробую спросить на другом ресурсе, тут явно непростой случай.